# How to launch another app from appcelerator's app

Tags: android, android-intent, appcelerator

I want to launch another app from my appcelerator's app. 
I have find this code but I'm not able to change it.

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
    url: 'activity1.js'
});
intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

My app to open from appcelerator's app named "Mobility".

How can I launch it?

> EDIT:
>   I have change my code in this but not works:

```
function launchAnotherApp(){
    var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
        className: 'it.mobility.LoginActivity',
        packageName: 'it.mobility'
    });
    intent.putExtra('username', "username");
    intent.putExtra('password', "password");
    //intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

this is the error:
{it.mobility/it.mobility.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
   var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action : Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
        packageName: 'it.eresult.sweetmobility',
        className : 'it.eresult.sweetmobility.activities.LoginActivity'
    });
    //set input data
    intent.putExtra('username', "user");
    intent.putExtra('password', "pass");

    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```